# How to push to an array given that the character is not already present in the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push to an initially empty array with the condition that the content at two different indexes of two different non-empty arrays don't have the same character and the initially empty array has not already pushed that character earlier

I've tried using the not operator, contains, includes, but nothing seems to work.

```
    var pushToArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {


        var characters = ["M", "U", "S", "I", "C"];
        var moreCharacters = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"];
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moreCharacters.length);

                                                      // && push to 'pushToArray' if the character is not in 'pushToArray'
        if (characters[i] != moreCharacters[randomIndex] && !pushToArray.includes(moreCharacters[randomIndex])) {

            pushToArray.push(moreCharacters[randomIndex]);
        }
```

`if(arrayContent1("I") == arrayContent2("I"))` then don't push

- Sample expected results for `pushToArray`:

`["F", "R", "E", "D", "L"]`

- Sample actual results for `pushToArray`:

`["I", "F", "R", "D", "Y"]`    I don't want that letter 'I' in there

Comment: What's wrong with the `"I"` at the first index? The first index of `characters` is not `"I"` after all, and there are no duplicates of `"I"` in `pushToArray` by the end. Do you actually want *no* characters of `pushToArray` to exist in `characters`, regardlexx of index?

Comment: What I'm trying to say with my if condition is that if the character from array1 is not equal to the character from array 2, AND the character from array2 is not already in the initially empty array known as array 3, then push the character from Array2 to Array3.

The only similar character between array1 and array2 is the character "I".

Comment: The `"I"` seems to fulfill both of those conditions. The first index of `characters` is not equal to `I`, nor is `I` already in `pushToArray` at the beginning (after all, `pushToArray` starts out empty)

Comment: At the fourth iteration of the for loop, isn't there a comparison with `characters[3]`, which is `"I"`, and `moreCharacters[randomIndex]`? Thanks

Comment: are you trying to do ArrayB - ArrayA = ArrayC? and Array C must contain the Unique characters?

Comment: @MuhammadZaib I want ArrayC to be Unique from ArrayA

Comment: No, on the third iteration, `characters[i] != moreCharacters[randomIndex]` resolves to `characters[2] != 'E'`, which is `false`, so `e` gets `push`ed

Comment: so you want something like this:

var array1 = ['A'. 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var array2= ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];

Result should be:

array3 = ['A', 'B'. 'C'] ?

Comment: @MuhammadZaib I would like `array3` to only have letters from `array2` that are not in `array1`. I basically don't want any letters that exist in `array1`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I could be wrong, but I thought that `randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moreCharacters.length);` Would give me a random value from 0 - 7?

Comment: @BayCode please check my answer below... You will get the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test

```
if (characters[i] != moreCharacters[randomIndex]
```

will fail only if `characters[i]` is the picked character - it sounds like you want to make sure that *none* of the `characters` match the picked character:

```
if (!characters.includes(moreCharacters[randomIndex])
```

If you're only conditionally pushing to the array, then change the `for` loop to

```
while (pushToArray.length < 5) {
```

```js
var pushToArray = [];
while (pushToArray.length < 5) {
  var characters = ["M", "U", "S", "I", "C"];
  var moreCharacters = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"];
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moreCharacters.length);

  // && push to 'pushToArray' if the character is not already in there
  if (!characters.includes(moreCharacters[randomIndex]) && !pushToArray.includes(moreCharacters[randomIndex])) {

    pushToArray.push(moreCharacters[randomIndex]);
  }
}
console.log(pushToArray);
```

But, the logic would be easier to follow if you filtered the `characters` out of `moreCharacters` beforehand:

```js
const excludeChars = ["M", "U", "S", "I", "C"];
const inputChars = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"]
  .filter(char => !excludeChars.includes(char));
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * inputChars.length);
  const [char] = inputChars.splice(randIndex, 1);
  result.push(char);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I know it took a while for me to explain what I was trying to achieve, so thanks for taking the time to help me out. The different code snippets are very informative. I appreciate it.

Comment: `const inputChars = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"]
  .filter(char => !excludeChars.includes(char));

` I see that you essentially made `const inputChars = ["F", "R", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"];`  

could you tell me how to read 

`const [char] = inputChars.splice(randIndex, 1);` 

I've never seen syntax like `const [someVariable]`

Comment: That's destructuring. `splice` returns an array of the removed items. `const [char] = <someArr>` means to put the first element of that array into a variable named `char`, and to disregard the rest, if there are any. It's like `const char = ..splice(...)[0]`

Comment: Is there a reason to use destructuring `const [char] = <someArr>` instead of a standard initialization `var char = <someArr>` in this instance?

Comment: Nvm. I think I figured it out... 
| splice returns an array of the removed items
| const [variable] is known as destructuring
| Destructuring is used to grab contents of the array | splice: inputChars.splice(randIndex,1) | Translation: at position randIndex return an array holding 'inputChar'[randomIndex] and remove that 1 item  from 'inputChar'

| If not for destructuring, multiple arrays with a single value inside them would be returned whereas with destructing, only the content would be sent because destructuring assigns the content to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This code does this:

> I would like array3 to only have letters from array2 that are not in array1. I basically don't want any letters that exist in array1

```js
var characters = ["M", "U", "S", "I", "C"];
var moreCharacters = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"];
var pushToArray = [];
var i, l = characters.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moreCharacters.length);
  // && push to 'pushToArray' if the character is not in 'pushToArray'
  if (!characters.includes(moreCharacters[randomIndex]) && !pushToArray.includes(moreCharacters[randomIndex])) {

    pushToArray.push(moreCharacters[randomIndex]);
  }
}
console.log(pushToArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved by doing:

```
var characters = ["M", "U", "S", "I", "C"];
var moreCharacters = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"];
var pushedToArray = [...characters].filter(x => moreCharacters.indexOf(x) === -1);
var finalArray = pushedToArray.filter((item, index) => pushedToArray.indexOf(item) === index);
```

Comment: Could you explain line 3 a bit more? I see that you used the array seperator syntax on `characters` and then I got lost with the filtering, the big arrow function, and  `indexOf(x) === -1);`

Comment: on line 3, spread operator is used to create keep the `characters` original array as is. `filter` method is used to push only those letters from `characters` array in `pushedToArray` that are not present in `moreCharacters`. and on line 4, we are simply removing the duplicates from `pushedToArray`

Comment: It's very close to what I wanted. I changed a little bit of your code up to make a bit closer:



`var characters = ["M", "U", "S", "I", "C"];
var moreCharacters = ["F", "R", "I", "E", "N", "D", "L", "Y"];
var pushedToArray = [...moreCharacters].filter(x => characters.indexOf(x) === -1);
var finalArray = pushedToArray.filter((item, index) => pushedToArray.indexOf(item) === index);
console.log(pushedToArray);`



Could you tell me what  `===-1` is for?

Comment: `indexOf` returns `-1` if a particular object is not found in array otherwise returns the index of that particular object in array. `===` is used for type checking...